# Can we allow defined predicates and functions in reflection?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

By Reflection I mean the following schema:

**Reflection:** $$\forall X \, (\varphi \implies \exists  \alpha : \varphi^{V_\alpha})$$

where $\varphi$ is a first order formula (defined predicates and functions allowed) in which only symbol "$X$" occurs free, $\varphi^{V_\alpha}$ is the "$\in {V_\alpha}$" bounded form of $\varphi$.

$V_\alpha$ is defined in the customary manner as the set of all subsets of elements of the range of a function from an ordinal $\alpha$ where the image of a successor is the power set of the image of its predecessor, and the image of a limit is the union of all images of prior ordinals. And ordinal is defined after von Neumann as a transitive set well ordered by $\in$.

The point here is that we are allowing the use of defined predicate and function symbols, as long as the formula remain first order, i.e. no quantification allowed over them.

Is reflection here a theorem scheme of $\sf ZF$?

Comment: Isn't this just equivalent to the standard reflection theorem, since you're only adding definable functions and predicates?

Comment: @FarmerS, do you mean this: " for any finite number of formulas of ZFC we can find a set Vα in the cumulative hierarchy such that all the formulas in the set are absolute for Vα (which means very roughly that they hold in Vα if and only if they hold in the universe of all sets)." [Wikipedia:Reflection principle]

Comment: @FarmerS, I think it would be but I don't know the proof. That's why I asked. But I came to know that this version of reflection without allowing definable functions and predicates would be a much weaker principle that it can be proved in ZFC. So, the addition of those does increase strength!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first answer took care of the case where "Reflection" was a scheme of formulas in the language of ZF. Now we consider what we now think was the intent of the questioner.

We expand the language of ZF by introducing a predicate symbol P and a function symbol F
for each formula  in the language of ZF. We also add additional axioms:

∀x1,...,xn(P(x1,...,xn)<-->(x1,...,xn)) where x1,...,xn are the free variables of .

∀x1,...,xn,y(∀z(((x1,...,xn,z)<-->y=z)-->F(x1,....xn)=y))

where x1,...,xn,y are the free variables of

∀x1,...,xn,y(((x1,...,xn,y)∧∃z(z≠y∧(x1,...,xn,z)))-->F(x1,...,xn)=0)

where x1,...,xn,y are the free variables of

Call this theory ZZF.

"Reflection" holds in ZZF.

Proof:Let  be a formula in the language of ZZF whose only free variable is X. Let A be the set of formulas  such that P is a symbol of . Let B be the set of formulas  such that F is a symbol of . To each term t ocurring in  we shall associate a variable vt where if s and t are not variables then

vs=vt iff s=t, and vs is not a variable of .

To each term we will also associate a formula ft. We will do this inductively as follows:

if w is a variable then  vw=w and fw is w=w.

if s=F(t1,...,tn) then

fs is f(t1)∧...∧f(tn)∧(v(t1),...,v(tn),v(s))

For each subformula θ of  we define a formula  θ*  in the language of ZF as follows:

(t1=t2)* is f(t1)∧f(t2)∧v(t1)=v(t2)

(t1∈t2)* is f(t1)∧f(t2)∧v(t1)∈v(t2)

(P(t1,...,tn))* is f(t1)∧...∧f(tn)∧(v(t1),...,v(tn))

(θ1∧θ2)* is (θ1)*∧(θ2)*

(¬θ)* is ¬(θ*)

(∃xθ)* is ∃x(θ*)

We note that θ*<-->θ for all subformulas θ of .

Now suppose (X).

By the usual notion of reflection there is an ordinal  such that X∈V, V reflects *, and V reflects all formulas of A and B.

Then *(X) holds with quantifiers relativized to V.

Therefore (X) holds relativized to V, since relativized to V, (X)<-->*(X).

Answer (score 1):

Each instance of the scheme referred to as  Reflection  is provable in ZF.

Suppose $\psi$ holds for some $X$. By the usual notion of reflection there is an ordinal $\alpha$ such that $X \in V_\alpha$  and $\forall y \, (y \in V_\alpha \implies ((V_\alpha \models \psi(y)) \iff \psi(y)))$. In particular $V_\alpha\models\psi(X)$.

Let $T$ be the theory axiomatized by extensionality, pairing, union, power set,
separation, and the scheme referred to as Reflection in this question.

Then $\operatorname{Con}(T)$ is provable in ZF.

Proof: For each set $s$, let
\begin{align*}
\mathsf A(s)=\{c \mid{} &c \text { is the least ordinal with } \\
& V_c\models \psi(x) \text { for some "formula" } \psi \land x \in s\}.
\end{align*}
Define a sequence $b$ of ordinals by $$b_0=0 \\ b_{n+1}=A(b_n).$$ Let $$\alpha =\bigcup \{b_n \mid n \in \omega\}.$$ Then the statement that "$T$ holds in $V_\alpha$" holds.

Comment: what is exactly the form of separation you are referring to, is it $\forall \vec{p} \forall A: \{x \in A \mid \phi\} $ exists whenever $\phi$ does't use symbol "$A$". If so, then the theory would be equivalent to $\sf ZF$ because Replacement would be easily proved, and so Con(T) cannot be proved in $\sf ZF$

Comment: Replacement is $\{f(x) \mid x \in X\}$ exists for every definable function $f$. Its easy to prove this by reflection here. Just reflect the formula $\exists s (s = X) \land \forall x \in X \exists y: y=f(x)$, then from separation on $V_\alpha$ we'd get our replacement set.

Comment: @Zuhaire: Suppose   is a formula and  defines your f. (x,y) need  not be equivalent 
 to (x,y) holds relativized to V.

Comment: It would be equivalent! That's the whole point from adding *defined* functions (and even predicates here) The point is to enforce that equivalence. The situation here is equivalent to saying that the open expansion of $f$ (i.e. the formula defining $f$) would not be relativized! Look at the formula I wrote in the comment above, there is no $\psi$ at all, you have $y=f(x)$ and this is defined say by $\psi$ beforehand, i.e. outside of reflection altogether.

Comment: I think this answer pertains to the form of reflection that doesn't allow the use of defined predicates or functions, or equivalently to the version where reflection would relativize the open expansion of those defined symbols. The theory here is different, and I believe its equivalent to ZF, and so cannot be proved consistent in ZF.